# HTML5 & Javascript Printer - Using mobile printer on webapp

Tags: html, mobile, printing

Thank You for spending time. I have a trouble with print on webapp with EP-58A printer.

**My problem is**: Wepapp Html can only be printed as pdf, so It was very slow in mobile printer. And my customer doesn't want to want to invest in building an Android app but He wants to improve mobile printer speed

**My concern is**: Is there any way or solutions to print only text from HTML5 - Javascript?

**UPDATE1:**
Thanks for Raphael's comment, but I have pre-prepared my printed zone, It has only text. I mean, I want these text will be printed as text, not PDF

Thank You for your help!

Comment: Apply media queries for printer with all img { display: none)

Comment: @Raphael thanks for reply,but my printed zone has only text, I wanna print as text, not PDF constain these text!

Comment: is your printing medium being set beforehand? and then you can choose if it's a pdf ot text, etc...

Comment: @Raphael The printer device has working properly and very fast in mobile app in the same phone

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: only thing coming to my mind is html version gererates more code, some additinal tables etc.. - therefore prinring in slower